# How to Use the BUILTIN.PERIOD in Netsuite SQL

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

According to this documentation:
Period - Returns the contents of the IN predicate for a relative date range as a subselection

I am not sure on how to use this one, and already tried every format, and I also tried this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064496/how-to-use-builtin-period): but no hope.

So far, here's what I tried:

```
require(['N/query', 'N/log'], function( query, log ) {
 var q = "select startdate from transaction where startdate IN(BUILTIN.PERIOD('LM', 'START', 'ALL', '<'))"
 var rs = query.runSuiteQL( {
   query: q
 });
 var mRS = rs.asMappedResults();
 console.log(mRS);
})
```